# Windows command line escape characters

Tags: windows, command-line, shell

Long story short: We receive a command from a script and want to execute it using windows shell.

Currently we use a method similar to:

`echo start & command & echo finish`

That works fine unless the command contains ampersands on its own, so for example

`echo begin & if exist c:\temp.txt echo 1 & echo end` will fail to write "end" if the file does not exist.

That can be solved by changing the command to `echo begin & (if exist c:\temp.txt echo 1) & echo end`, but then we run into problems for commands that contain parentheses symbols, for example

`echo begin & (echo %PATH%) & echo end` prints "\Hewlett-Packard\HP was unexpected at this time." because I have Program Files (x86) in path.

Any way to escape special characters from the command's result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your best bet is to split the three commands (echo start, command, and echo finish) onto three separate lines.  How are you actually launching the command?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the spaces in the PATH, so use quotes.

```
  echo begin & (echo "%PATH%") & echo end
```

Comment: Thanks and right, but we have no control of the command that comes from the script, it may not be an echo command at all